# How to read a Kubernetes Deployment with python kubernetes client

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

what is python kubernetes client equivalent for

```
kubectl get deploy -o yaml
```

[CRUD python Client example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/deployment_crud.py)

i referred this example for getting python deployment
but there is no read deployment option

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`read_namespaced_deployment()` does the thing:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
api = client.AppsV1Api()

deployment = api.read_namespaced_deployment(name='foo', namespace='bar')
```

Comment: Hi Where can i find the documents for python client

Comment: @sri05 https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the list of deployments (not only one):

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

api = client.AppsV1Api()

deployments: client.V1DeploymentList = api.list_deployment_for_all_namespaces()
```